# WPF Prism Unity - RegisterType with InjectionConstructor

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, unity-container, prism

I have a simple .Net Core WPF/PRISM/Unity App, that has a Class like this:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(string someMessage)
    {

    }
}

public interface IMyClass
{
}
```

In App.Xaml.cs I have the following:

```
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        Container.GetContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic());
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<MainWindow>();

        containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType(
            typeof(IMyClass), 
            typeof(MyClass), 
            "", 
            new TransientLifetimeManager(), 
            new InjectionConstructor("Some nice message"));
    }
}
```

But if I try to inject IMyClass...

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly IMyClass myClass;

    public MainWindow(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }
```

I get the following error:

Unity.ResolutionFailedException: 'The current type, WpfApp7.IMyClass, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

---

Exception occurred while:

·resolving type:  'IMyClass'
  for parameter:  'myClass'
  on constructor:  MainWindow(IMyClass myClass)
   ·resolving type:  'MainWindow'

I did an Console App - with no Prism - and did the same code, it just worked nicely.

Comment: When and how do you create `MainWindow`? I suppose you erroneously try to create it before your registration is done.

Comment: I create the MainWindow in the CreateShell method already.

Comment: As a side note, I should add that it's a bit dubious to inject stuff into a _view_. What stuff might a view have to do that requires a service to do so that is so closely coupled to the view that it cannot be done in the view model...?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `MainWindow` in your `CreateShell()` method. This works:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType(
        typeof(IMyClass),
        typeof(MyClass),
        "",
        new TransientLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor("Some nice message"));
    }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(string s)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..., using this generic method instead.

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(new InjectionConstructor(new object[] { "Works Nicely" }));
```

Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Solved what? You don't have to use the generic method to be able to resolve the type obviously.

Comment: The generic version is more explicit in that it obviously registers as default, whereas the non-generic might lead one to believe that he unintentionally registers namedly, even though with an empty name. So I'd perfer the generic version any time, but I'd still be interested in what the problem originially might have been.

Comment: I agree but using the generic overload instead of the non-generic one has *nothing* to do with the original issue.

Comment: That's why I'm interessted in what caused the problem originally, and what solved it.